# How to reuse MotorCortex incidents

Tags: javascript, motorcortex, donkeyclip

I have a clip that I develop and I want to reuse a fade in incident instead o creating a new incident every time is this possible? The way I am doing it at the moment looks like this:\

```
const attrs = {animatedAttrs:{opacity:1}}
const props = {selector:".elem",duration:1000}
const fadeInOne = new CSSEffect(attrs,props)
const fadeInTwo = new CSSEffect(attrs,props)
clip.addIncindet(fadeOne,1000)
// do something else and then later on
clip.addIncident(fadeTwo,1000)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why not using a function to create the fadeIn incident?

Comment: Can you provide an example? How can someone do what you're saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish what you want you could do the following:

```
const attrs = {animatedAttrs:{opacity:1}}
const props = {selector:".elem",duration:1000}
const fadeIn = () => new CSSEffect(attrs,props)

clip.addIncindet(fadeIn(),1000)
// do something else and then later on
clip.addIncident(fadeIn(),1000)
```

**Note** *: you could add argument to the fadeIn function and make some of the data dynamic such as the selector or the duration, or event add different easing.